# PHP File Editor - Working out some bugs

Tags: php, html

I have made an online file editor and file manager script for my web development company so that our hosted website users can manage their own files and edit their templates as they feel fit. It is coded in PHP and allows users to edit html, text, php, js, jquery, and any text based file. Since we only really support english languages and code everything in utf-8, it has been built to support the utf-8 encoding.

Unfortunately, there is a small issue I noticed during testing. Since I am using `htmlentities` and then using `html_entities_decode` when they are saved (submitted), anything a user enters that they WANT to stay as an `htmlentity` is then also converted by my code.

Here is an image to illustrate the issues we are experiencing:
[image]

Here's the process I am using to write to the contents of the textarea to the original file:

```
if(isset($_POST['filecontents'])) {
    $contents = $_POST['filecontents'];
    $filecontents = html_entity_decode($contents, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $fileloc = "/htdocs/usr/". $_POST['filename'];
    $filewrite = fopen($fileloc, "w");
    fwrite($filewrite, $filecontents);
    fclose($filewrite);
    die();
}
```

Since I am using htmlentities to output the file into an editable textarea it comes out looking proper in the text area, but when it is saved, it converts all the items instead of just the ones I want converted, so when they resubmit the page, they lose copyright symbols, registered symbols, menu buttons and the like. If I **DON'T** use the htmlentities before I output it to the page, then any php script code will try and run because its being echoed out and any closing tags like `</textarea>` could cause huge issues for the script.

**Question time:**:
Is there a way to properly replace all of the open and close tags, ie `<` and `>` in the file with their `htmlentities` alternative but not replace ANY other entity in the script? That way anything else that is entered will be properly saved into the file afterwards.

Comment: Couldn't you just give an extra 'flag' when a user edits text content, so that won't be replaced using htmlentities? Like an extra get parameter.

Comment: You should _not_ encode it before you save it, but you _should_ encode it before you output it in the textarea (or any other place, for that matter) and that won't break anything. If you have PHP-code in a string, it won't be executed unless you run it through `eval()` (which you don't seem to be doing).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes but I am already encoding it on the output of the page, the problem like I said in my question is that since all htmlentities are encoded not just the open and close tags, that any entity entered by users BEFORE the post is converted (like &copy;) is also decoded into the © symbol even though we don't want it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call `html_entity_decode()`.

`htmlentities()` is necessary to insert arbitrary content into HTML source.
However, the POST from the browser is raw text, and is not HTML encoded.

Comment: @Kaboom: Yes; that's because you're decoding the entities using `html_entity_decode`.  Don't do that.

Comment: No; the input you get in your POST is not HTML encoded in the first place.  You need to understand how encoding works; it's only for assembling strings.

Comment: I will stick with your method and see what happens